# unable to install or enable commerce modules via admin interface in commerce kickstart 2

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-commerce, commerce

For some reason, I am having a world of trouble enabling commerce modules in my commerce kickstart 2 install. I first noticed it when trying to enable autosku which is installed with the kickstart profile. Enabling it in the module page does not work, after saving it remains unchecked. Only way to enable it was to set status to 1 in the system table. After that I noticed the autosku table wasn't in my database, which means that the module's .install did not run. I tried to force it to run via devel execute php but nothing happened. When I delete the module's row in the system table and run update.php, nothing happens - except the module is disabled again... When I go and look in my system table, the module's row is back. In my last attempt, I exported the necessary table from a local kickstart install and imported it, which makes it work.

The same problem arises with commerce order fieldgroup panes, commerce backoffice etc. Strange thing is, I don't have this problem with non-commerce modules, e.g. GA, i18n etc - they remain enabled and their tables are created, so I suppose my database permissions are OK. Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it! For some reason, the schema version of the problematic modules was set to -1, making it appear to drupal as if they're uninstalled. I changed the schema version of the modules to 0 in the system table and ran update.php, which added the necessary changes in the tables. Hope this helps others out as well.